# What is the difference in /home locations between nautilus and the command-line?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, home-directory

I cannot understand why in the bash, the path for (let's say) the Videos folder is `/home/ioannis/Videos` and in the Nautilus is `/home/Home/Videos`. This is what it looks like:

**Bash**

[image]

**Nautilus**

[image]

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Please edit your question so you only ask one question per post. There is a question about partitioning (that is likely a duplicate) and another one about Nautilus funny naming. Split them into two questions.

Comment: Adding to Javier Rivera's note, please also make sure not to add signatures in your future questions as there is [a rule against this](http://askubuntu.com/faq#signatures). Thanks and welcome to Ask Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think Nautilus just changes the actual path to visually show 'Home' instead. The path is not different in Nautilus, it just shows it like that in the GUI.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in nautilus to view the actual path.

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus use the word "Home" to identify your /home/ directory.

When it shows the path in the breadcrumb, the first "home" is the actual /home dir, and the second one ("Home") represents your /home/ directory.

This substitution makes sense is some cases - I think it's easier for the user to identify the home folder by the name "Home", instead of the username. But it can be confusing in situations like this, though.